# Application.Calculation property

Tags: excel, properties, vba

I am facing an issue. Sometimes when I open a workbook (that has no macro) my calculation method is changed to Manual. Researching on the problem I've found the following causes.

> Testing has shown that the calculation setting is set to Automatic by
> default. It will only be set to Manual if:
>
> (1) you have changed the
> default workbook to one that has the calculation mode set to Manual;
>
> (2) if there is some sort of AutoOpen macro that sets the calculation
> mode;
>
> (3) if you have some automatically loading workbooks (XLSX or
> XLTX, including the Personal workbook) that have calculation set to
> Manual; or
>
> (4) if you start Excel by double-clicking, in Windows, on a
> workbook that has calculation set to Manual.

I don't understand the explanation for causes (1),(3),(4) since Application.Calculation is an application level property. Can someone explain me what is the relationship of a workbook with the application property?

Comment: When you open a workbook it launches the application, with its settings

Comment: [relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106544/how-to-set-calculation-mode-to-manual-when-opening-an-excel-file)

Comment: With the workbook's settings? I thought it would launch the application with the application settings, settings set by the user.

Comment: Workbooks can set application settings. Say you want automatic, but you open a workbook that's manual - it's going to change the automatic to manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel sets its initial calculation mode from the first non-addin, non-template workbook opened in an Excel session. Then the second workbook opened does not alter the calculation mode, but of course VBA or the user can alter it.