# Stop calculations on one shared Excel sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

As the title suggests, I have a workbook with a large amount of calculations across multiple sheets. I would like to be able to disable the calculations in the workbook until a user presses F9. This is easily doable through the options section.

The issue is that the file is shared, and different users have different options set (most have autocalc set). Is there any way of setting the options tab to manual calculate for the sheet, so that it overrides the users preferences? (I know that I can do this in VBA, but I don't want to go down that route for this).

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this, or is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cf [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/214395) :

> The first document that is opened uses the calculation mode with which it was last saved. Documents that are opened later use the same mode. For example, if you open Auto1.xlsx and then open Manual1.xlsx, both documents use automatic calculation (the mode used by Auto1.xlsx). If you open Manual1.xlsx and then open Auto1.xlsx, both documents use manual calculation.

If your document is saved in manual mode AND is the first one to be opened by other users, it will be opened in manual mode.

But if the user already has a workbook open in automatic mode, the new workbook will open in automatic mode.

You state explicitly you don't want to use VBA, but it's just [a few lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106544/how-to-set-calculation-mode-to-manual-when-opening-an-excel-file) so I put the code here :

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.Calculation = xlManual
    Application.CalculateBeforeSave = False
End Sub
```