# Creative way to work with large model (potentially using excel macros/vba)

Tags: excel, vba, large-files

I created a 80.7MB excel file. The basic structure of the file is the user enters inputs on one sheet, formulas are run in a different sheet (hidden), and outputs are displayed on a third sheet.

My problem is the hidden sheet with the formulas is 68MB alone so my start up speed on the file are around 8-9 minutes. However, once open, the model runs quickly and has never crashed.

I am trying to reduce the start-up speed for this file.

My initial idea was to move the formulas to a separate workbook (Workbook 2) and run a macro in the original sheet (Workbook 1) to open Workbook 2 in the background (not visible to the user). This reduced the start up to 2-3 minutes (to just open the 2 files) however to run the model properly the links need to be updated which take a long time to load.

Is there a way to eliminate the time needed to link these sheets when they are both open?

Or even better does anyone have any ideas regarding the most efficient way to reduce the start up speed while still having my model function properly?

Comment: Replace whatever you're doing on the 2nd sheet with VBA. But we can't help you without more information. Try to break down your model into several steps and share each attempt in a separate question.

Comment: Are the files loaded from a network share or from the local machine? There may be some network delay involved in loading the 2nd sheet.

Comment: Set [`Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlcalculation) and only calculate the formulas when you need them. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106544/how-to-set-calculation-mode-to-manual-when-opening-an-excel-file

Comment: Welcome Alek! Read [The Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and earn your first badge!